# How to match possible filenames in problem-matcher rule

Tags: annotations, github-actions

I want to match possible alternatives of filename using [problem matcher file](https://github.com/actions/toolkit/blob/main/docs/problem-matchers.md) so that Github Actions annotations are created when the `appstream-util`'s output matches the rules. While I successfully matched problematic lines, I'm unable to get filename to be annotated as well.

I have this sample output when running `appstream-util`:

```
data/com.vixalien.sticky.appdata.xml: FAILED:
• markup-invalid        : <id> has invalid character [@]
• value-missing         : <!-- Copyright [year] [name] --> is not present
 ...
```

and this problem-matcher file (.github/matchers/appstream-validation.json):

```json
{
    "problemMatcher": [
        {
            "owner": "appstream-validation",
            "pattern": [
                {
                    "regexp": "^(.*\\.(appdata|metainfo)\\.(x|y)ml): FAILED:$",
                    "file": 1
                },
                {
                    "regexp": "^.\\s+(\\w+-invalid|\\w+-missing|tag-duplicated|translations-required|duplicate-data|url-not-found)\\s+:\\s+(.*)$",
                    "code": 1,
                    "message": 2,
                    "loop": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to match the [appstream filename as accepted by `appstream-util`](https://github.com/hughsie/appstream-glib/blob/cbe4aae01a99154464cb865235689bf49d0a48a2/data/appstream-util#L42), so its name should match 'appdata' or 'metainfo', and '.yml' or '.xml'.

In this particular case, try to match `data/com.vixalien.sticky.appdata.xml: FAILED:`, but I'm trying to be more generic as possible.

The problem-matcher and the workflow files can be found in my [GitHub fork in add-matcher branch](https://github.com/rffontenelle/sticky/tree/add-matcher) under .github directory. There are also workflow run logs.

Answer (score 0):

Annotations for filenames are only possible for source files. This can be easy to overlook, but with enough peace for thinking it may become obvious - or at least understandable - as these files are not persisting with the Git repository, so why annotate them?

`data/com.vixalien.sticky.appdata.xml` is not part of the source tree.

So the annotation is only displayed in the summary page of the action, and you may see error/warning highlighting in the logs depending on matcher severity settings.

[image: annotations in the summary]

*([run summary with annotations: Add problem matcher #20](https://github.com/rffontenelle/sticky/actions/runs/5025514328))*

You can, however, make your own results with the [checks API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/checks?apiVersion=2022-11-28), so they are more visible. This in case you're looking for an alternative approach for errors from a build not checking a source file.